# Bridging for Eclipse plugin to C# Addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, eclipse-plugin

We have designed some Eclipse plugins using EMF.Now we want those plugins to give support for the C# addin.So we though of porting those Eclipse plugins to C#. So we found tools that gives support for porting from Eclipse plugins to C# Addin are  JNBridge and IKVM.Since our plugins are built on Eclipse modelling framework is there any way can we proceed for porting using those tools.Will it be valid in C# addin as in Eclipse.Will it provide the same functionality after porting from Eclipse plugins to C#.

Even tools that provide porting from java to C# is not clear about they can give the facility to port the Eclipse plugins to the C# Addin.

So if this idea possible thing or not?Because after some research we found one project proposal in Eclipse called EMF4Net.But this project was withdrawn.So can we proceed with this or not why?Can i know the valid reason

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the JNBridge tool, [JNBridgePro](http://jnbridge.com/software/jnbridgepro/overview), you should be able to leverage your EMF Model and Adapter classes in C#. It's not clear to me how much of the Editor classes you can leverage, though I do know that the JFace widgets aren't embed-able on the .NET side (only AWT, Swing supported). You'll probably want to use .NET WinForms or WPF for the add-in GUI, anyway.

JNBP generates an assembly of .NET proxy classes from the JAR files. The proxy classes represent the Java classes while coding. At run-time, The proxy objects execute in the CLR, bridging via shared memory to the actual Java objects executing in the JVM. The JNBridgePro Visual Studio add-in (the dev tool that generates the proxy assemblies from the JARs) in fact does this itself.

Comment: But JNBridge tool is not clear that 100% of EMF model can be bridged to C#

Comment: Whether the JNBridge can be used for Eclipse plugins to .net addins